# Django query for model with a single DateField used for tracking state changes

Tags: django, database, orm, django-queryset

I have searched all over StackOverflow / Reddit / etc, but can't seem to find anything like this.

Assuming we have the following model (purposely simplified):

```
class X(models.Model):
    related_object = models.ForeignKey(Y)
    start_date = models.DateField(unique=True)
    is_rented = models.BooleanField()
```

Where model X is tracking state changes of an instance of model Y. It could be tracking something like the state of cars at a car rental agency that may be rented out. A new instance of the model is created each time the state of each car changes.

The resulting objects might look something like this:

```
{"id" : 1, "related_object" : 2, "start_date" : "2021-03-03", "is_rented" : False},
{"id" : 2, "related_object" : 2, "start_date" : "2021-03-06", "is_rented" : False},
{"id" : 3, "related_object" : 2, "start_date" : "2021-03-10", "is_rented" : True},
{"id" : 4, "related_object" : 2, "start_date" : "2021-03-15", "is_rented" : False},
{"id" : 5, "related_object" : 2, "start_date" : "2021-03-16", "is_rented" : True},
{"id" : 6, "related_object" : 4, "start_date" : "2021-03-16", "is_rented" : False},
{"id" : 7, "related_object" : 2, "start_date" : "2021-03-17", "is_rented" : False},
{"id" : 8, "related_object" : 4, "start_date" : "2021-03-22", "is_rented" : True},
```

I want to be able to perform the following queries:

1. For a provided date, return only the X instance that is active for that date
2. For a provided date range, return all X instances that overlap with the range

Everything I find on SO seems to involve models with both start and end date fields. In this case, we are assuming that a model instance continues in it's state until a new instance is created with a date further into the future that a previous instance. For instance, the instance with id=1 above would essentially have an end date of 2021-03-06. Both instance id=7 and id=8 essentially do not have an end date (forever into the future) until a new instance is created with dates after theirs.

It seems like this should be a really common use case anytime someone wants to track state changes and the end date isn't necessarily known. Or I may want to be able to insert a new record between, say, id=3 and id=4, with a date of 2021-03-11, and I shouldn't have to recalculate the value of id=3 to adjust the end date manually.

Examples:

- If I query for instances of X where related_object=2 and the date I'm
  interested in is 2021-03-07, I should get back the X instance where
  id=2.
- If I query for instances of X where related_object=2 and the range of
  dates I am interested in are 2021-03-04 through 2021-03-11, I should
  get back the X instances of id=1, 2, and 3, but because id=1 has a date that starts below the date of the query, it will get excluded, even though it's status was active on 2021-03-04.

**Any recommendations for how to approach this?**

Comment: not sure , if I understood your question , but can't you simply query all records of model x which are less than a particular date for e.g. 2021-03-07 and then find out the most recent date

Comment: That does work for querying a single time. I appreciate it! But it still doesn't account for range queries (the second part of my question, and the second example at the end)

Comment: I think you're looking for Window functions (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions).  They would allow you to select the start date of the _next_ ordered row, and treat that as an effective end date.

Comment: @TimNyborg I think you might be right. I haven't used Window functions much, and was hoping there was a more straightforward approach. Guess I have some reading/learning to do :(

Comment: to solve second part of your question, can you use two queries , find out the most recent date just like part 1 for lower date in the range for e.g. 2021-03-04 , this will give you 2021-03-03 as a result , now use this as lower date in your range and query all records for which start_date is grater or equal to 2021-03-03 and less than 2021-03-11